# Is there a way to make LaTeX interpret ``Nested `quotation''' as “Nested ‘quotation’”?

Tags: punctuation, nesting

I know there is `csquotes` but is there a way to make nested quotation marks as in

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
``Nested `quotation'''
\end{document}
```

to show up as as “Nested ‘quotation’”?

That is, as

[image: “Nested ‘quotation’”]

because the normal behaviour will be to typeset it as “Nested ‘quotation”’

[image: “Nested ‘quotation”’]

And if there is no such automatic way of doing it, what is the most elegant way to force LaTeX to use the correct nesting? I came up with using `"` instead of `''` but I can't say I like it very much since it is incongruent with the rest of my document.

Comment: While this question is closed as a duplicate, you can still accept Barbara's answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

one approach is

```
``Nested `quotation'{}''
```

if the closing quotes are too close together, use the approach suggested by knuth
(*TeXbook*, p.5; okay, it's a double dangerous bend):

```
``Nested `quotation'\thinspace''
```

or, in latex-speak:

```
``Nested `quotation'\,''
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't list your first solution since I found it even uglier than using `"`. Anyway, maybe a thin space isn't such a bad idea typographically even.